# Finder. No folder icon after upgrade to 10.10.3

Tags: macos, finder, upgrade

After upgrade there is no folder icon in Finder:

[image]

Does somebody have problem like this? Could you maybe help me with some advice?

PS. Everything is ok with list view option in Finder.

Comment: It looks like it only applies to apps that the os x does not know what do with. Open one of those with Open with to test..  Other than that it looks perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `killall -KILL Finder` in Terminal. Usually clears up graphical glitches.

Try resetting Finder preferences. Run these commands in Terminal:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
killall -KILL Finder
```

Note that you will have to redo any Finder preferences you had set.

If that doesn't work, follow [these steps](http://furbo.org/2015/01/19/clearing-the-icon-services-cache-in-yosemite/) to reset the Icon Services cache:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ \
-name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;

sudo find /private/var/folders/ \
-name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;

sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store

killall -KILL Dock
killall -KILL Finder
```

After the first command, it will prompt you for a password. Enter your login password.

Comment: Now worse than was before
https://www.dropbox.com/s/brth9pbknpbvtny/Screenshot%202015-04-16%2000.49.50.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you reboot afterwords? Also try resetting Finder preferences. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried all step-by-step. Maybe there is no such icons on disk? Do you know correct path to them?

maybe copy icons form other mac will be good idea?

Comment: System icons are stored in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources` so unless you somehow managed to muck up that bundle, I doubt they are missing entirely.

Comment: This is what I see in this folder. https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9ir6d5vw6rt393/Screenshot%202015-04-16%2001.17.10.png?dl=0

could you provide your folder with icons?

Comment: Try running the combo updater from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804). It should fix any missing file problems.

Comment: +1 for combo updater - a sadly-neglected resource, good for fixing many odd glitches.

Comment: If you haven't used Disk Utility to repair permissions, try that. it's quick and easy to do. If it has problems that it can't easily fix boot into recovery mode and repair the disk and then permissions.

Comment: Neither combo updater nor Disk Utility help me. :( But Disk Utility have fixed a lot of errors but dirs icons still are not visible.